# Math.sin() is giving me Math Domain Error

Tags: python

I am making a program to create an image of the mandelbrot set as a .ppm file.
I tried implementing a rudimentary version of "[normalized iteration count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plotting_algorithms_for_the_Mandelbrot_set#Continuous_(smooth)_coloring)", when math.sin() started giving me a math domain error.
Math.sin() shouldn't have a domain, right? I'm stumped...

```py
import math
def ask(question):
    return float(input(question))
maxIts=ask("max iterations? ")
size=int(ask("image side length? "))
sideTuple=(round(-size/2),round(size/2))
ppmFile=["P3",str(size),str(size),"255"]
def getV(z,n):
    return n-math.log2(math.log10(z))
def addValue(v):
        for i in range(0,3):
            ppmFile.append(str(math.sin(v)))
def iterate(x,y):
    coord=complex(x,y)
    i=0
    z=coord
    while i<maxIts and z.real<10:
        z=(z*z)+coord
        i+=1
    if z.real>10:
        addValue(getV(z.real,i))
    else:
        ppmFile.append("0 0 0")
def render(x,y,scale):
    for j in range(*sideTuple):
        for i in range(*sideTuple):
            iterate(4*i/(scale*size)+x,4*j/(scale*size)-y)
render(ask("x position? "),ask("y position? "),ask("zoom? "))
newFile=open("brotPPM.ppm","w")
newFile.write(" ".join(ppmFile))
newFile.close
```

Putting in 256, 1000, 0, 0, and 1 as inputs gave me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\Downloads\Python\brotPPM_v4.py", line 34, in <module>
    render(ask("x position? "),ask("y position? "),ask("zoom? "))
  File "C:\Users\Me\Downloads\Python\brotPPM_v4.py", line 32, in render
    iterate(4*i/(scale*size)+x,4*j/(scale*size)-y)
  File "C:\Users\Me\Downloads\Python\brotPPM_v4.py", line 24, in iterate
    addValue(getV(z.real,i))
  File "C:\Users\Me\Downloads\Python\brotPPM_v4.py", line 13, in addValue
    ppm.append(str(math.sin(v)))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: math domain error
```

Comment: *"Math.sin() shouldn't have a domain"* - What? It's a function. Every function has a domain.

Comment: that likely means that at some point you pass a complex number or something, since sin has a domain of the full set of real numbers

Comment: The code in the error message isn't in your program, btw.

Comment: What did you get when you did `print(v)`?

Comment: apparently v ends up as negative infinity on one of the iterations (which i saw from a breakpoint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap `addValue` in a try-catch statement, you can show what value of `v` or what value of `z` is the problem.

It turns out to be infinities. Sometimes, the real part of `z` escapes to infinity, and then you'll end up with an infinite value being passed to `math.sin`. Consider mapping infinity to its own colour.

```
def getV(z, n):
    v = n - math.log2(math.log10(z))
    try:
        return math.sin(v)
    except ValueError:
        return 42 # ??

def addValue(v):
        for i in range(3):
            ppmFile.append(str(v))
```

---

By the way, you don't close the file at the end (unless you forgot to include the parentheses when pasting your code here), which may or may not end up being a problem. By using a context manager, you can be sure the file is closed at the end:

```
with open("brotPPM.ppm","w") as newFile:
   newFile.write(" ".join(ppmFile))
```